# Getting Gender of People in Google + in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I have been trying to create an android app where I could Use Google + login. When I try to get data from the Google +, I am getting Gender as Male ("0") for all Google + users despite their Gender being Female in the actual Google + page.

Is this a bug from Google plus, or Is their anything like permission needed ?

^^^^^^^^Edit^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I called `mPlusClient.connect();`

and then in the `onConnected()` I called `mPlusClient.loadVisiblePeople(this, null);`

In the `onPeopleLoaded` method I called `personBuffer.get(i).getGender()`.
I am getting the gender as 0.

**Note:** I am getting the Display name , Profile Image in the same way as getting Gender and It is working fine.

Comment: Can u say Y you "-1" d it?

Comment: "0" is not a valid gender so you do not appear to be using the APIs correctly. If you update your question with more specific details on what API methods you are using and how you are using them we would be better able to help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java so I can't specifically help with that. I would recommend you check the specific profiles with the [try it tool](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) and see if they have the gender set through the API.

Comment: Ok. 'll try it out.. Thank u

Comment: @abraham - why do you say that "0" is not a valid gender?  According to http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.Gender.html the field is an `int` and the value for male is in fact 0.  It doesn't seem like there's support for "unspecified" but "other" (2) is a choice.

Comment: Because the [G+ API docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people) listed `"male"`, `"female"`, and `"other"` as the values. It looks like the Android API handles it differently though.

Comment: Did you get it working? What did u do? Added any extra scope? 
I am not able to fetch Gender and Birthday of friends list from G+ android SDK.

Comment: Kindly see the answer updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked. Need to add permissions to access gender and other details of people within the circle. The code snippet is:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setActions(
                "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE).build();
```